# How to find Minimum of Function with Many Local Minima

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, algorithms, monte-carlo, gradient-descent

I'm trying to find the smallest local minima within a given boundary condition, e.g., a circle. Currently, I'm using a monte carlo algorithm to approximate the minimum, followed by a gradient descent to hone in on the particular point. I would rather only use the gradient descent but it gets stuck in all the local minima.

The problem is that the monte carlo isn't accurate enough either, so I get different minima each time. This wouldn't be a problem if they at least had the same z value, but they don't more often than not.

How should I go about designing this algorithm?

**Edit:** The function, $G_{R}(x,y)$ to optimize is defined below.

$f(r)$ is a continuous piecewise equation composed of linear segments defined for $x \geq 0$. E.g.,

$$f(r) =
\begin{cases}
1-r,  & 0 \leq r \lt 1/2 \\
2-3r, & 1/2 \leq r \lt 2/3 \\
0, & r \geq 2/3
\end{cases}$$

g rotates the function, f, about the z axis, making look like a hill.
$$g(x,y) = f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$$

$g_{n,m}$ centers the hill at $(x_{n,m},y_{n,m})$.
$$g_{n,m}(x,y) = g(x-x_{n,m},y-y_{n,m}) $$

The centers are triangulated throughout $\Bbb R^2$. $\alpha$ is some constant.
$$x_{n,m} = \alpha (n+\frac{|n|}{n} \frac{1+(-1)^{m+1}}{4}) $$
$$y_{n,m} = \alpha (m \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}) $$

Plot of $(x_{n,m},y_{n,m})$ for $R = 120$ and $\alpha = 30 $
[image: Plot of Centers]

The final function sums over all the centers within a circle of radius R, like a macro hill that is the superposition of all the micro hills.
$$G_{R}(x,y) = \sum_{n,m\in \Bbb Z}^{n^2+m^2 \leq R^2} g_{n,m}(x,y)$$

Plot of $G_{R}(x,y)$
[image: Plot of function with many local minima]

**Edit 2:**

The problem is highlighted in the following figure. The algorithm must find the absolute minimum within the red circle. It finds the red dot, as there are many relative minima with that value within the red circle. However, the absolute minimum is at the purple dot, of which there are fewer values.

[image]

**Edit 3:**
The function, $G_R$ is further optimized by linear factors $\beta_{n,m}$.

$$G_R(x,y) = \sum_{n,m\in\Bbb Z}^{n^2+m^2\leq R^2}\beta_{n,m}g_{n,m}(x,y) $$

Some of the $g_{n,m}(x,y)$ are scaled up and others down in order to minimize the difference between the max and min. To keep the number of variables being optimized low, the $\beta$ are equivalent for $(x_{n,m}
,y_{n,m})$ of equal radii.

$$\beta_{n,m} = \beta_{i,j} \text{ if } x_{n,m}^2+y_{n,m}^2 = x_{i,j}^2+y_{i,j}^2$$

After optimizing with the $\beta$, the distribution looks like this:

[image]

So the optimization has to work over at least one quadrant.

A close-up of he last picture:

[image]

Comment: Would it be practical for you to find the smallest value attained along any given radius? You would then be able to convert your 2d problem into a 1d problem.

Comment: @CarlChristian I do need to minimize over at least one quadrant, but I suppose I could do it one radius at a time. It seems like this would be similar to just calculating every value by brute force, though, no?

Comment: Do you have a formula for the function?

Comment: @rych I edited the question to show the function.

Comment: I suppose your choice of $\alpha$ is such that the hills overlap? There is a symmetry to your $x$ and $y$ locations. Your search can be localized in the areas of the circle $R$ where these points are least clustered together.  This should locate a global minima. If you had more randomized locations, then one technique to search for global minima is a meta heuristic like simulated annealing

Comment: @player100 Close; $\alpha$ is chosen to minimize the distance between the global maxima and constrained global minima, i.e., to "flatten" the surface. Yes, the symmetry allows me to restrict the search to a single quadrant. Could you please explain your, "least clustering," idea a little more? I can always generate more random points via the monte carlo, if that's what you're suggesting.

Comment: @player100 Yes, $\alpha$ is chosen such that the hills overlap and minimize the distance between the global maximum and constrained global minimum.

Comment: Can you provide a plot of $x_{m,n}$ and $y_{m,n}?

Comment: @player100 Sure. I just edited in a plot of the centers.

Comment: Based on the symmetry wouldn’t the minima be at the corners of the domain?

Comment: @player100 If the circle is chosen with a large enough radius, $r_{\text{flat}}$ (the radius of the red circle in the figure), then the minimum will be at the edge. However, the objective of the algorithm is to choose $\alpha$ such that there is a flat, "egg crate" looking area in the center and find the absolute minimum within that egg crate. Then, the higher level algorithm finds the radius at which that minimum is still the minimum. I'll edit in a new figure to help explain.

Comment: *The, the higher level algorithm finds the **largest** radius at which that minimum is still the minimum.

Comment: My intuition is that there are many equal local mins centered at the center of every 6 hex points...  sometimes what you are experiencing is maybe a sampling error when you define the gridpts where you evaluate the function. Btw, the global mins are clearly at the corners....

Comment: @player100 Your intuition is close. The local minima are actually at some fraction of a distance between any two sources. For example, consider two hills that overlap. The local minimum will be halfway between the two hills. The problem gets complicated after a third hill introduces the next variable, but there are still minima at some fraction (I'm not sure if it's exactly 1/3) of the distance between each source. The problem is further complicated by how jagged the initial distribution function, f(r), is.

Comment: @player100 Why are the global minima clearly at the corners? The data don't support that. In the last figure I edited in, the purple point is at (82,0) but the search radius is 100.

Comment: @player100 If you think the right way to go is by searching for a formulaic solution through analyzing the geometric structure, then we have to consider another detail. Within $G_R(x,y)$, each of the $g_{n,m}(x,y)$ is optimized by a linear factor, $\beta_{n,m}$, scaling some up and some down in order to reduce the difference between the max and min. This flattening process also uses monte carlo followed by gradient descent on the $\beta_{n,m}$. To keep the number of variables low, the $\beta$ are equal $(x_{n,m},y_{n,m})$ of equal radius, i.e., it optimizes by rings of hills.

Comment: @player100 I edited the question to show a plot after the $\beta$ are calculated. The max/min algorithm has to work on those types of surfaces as well, which definitely don't have the global minimum at the edge.

Comment: Interesting. What is the support of $f(r)$? In other words, at what $r_{max}$ does $f(r_{max}) = 0$?. The problem becomes complicated with $g_{n,m}$. I still think you can use something like simulated annealing to do this optimizing, but this is a slower process.

Comment: @player100 The support of $f(r)$ just depends on how it's defined. In the example I gave in the question, it's for $r \geq 2/3$, but for the figures it's around 100. Is that important for something? Do you know of any java libraries for simulated annealing? Or any good guide sources for writing my own? Also, I investigated the fractional minimum a little further and found a result that you will find interesting. The algebraic minimum is actually just the average of all the radii for the centers. Its value hold up pretty well pre-optimization too. I'm going to link to a new question.

Comment: @player100 I posted the results here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2981202/solution-of-the-following-equation. I approximated $g_{n,m}(r)$ with $e^{-{(r-r_{n,m})}^2}$ (which I just condensed down to one index, n), and differentiated. The result is pretty accurate without $\beta$ being calculated, but now I've asked if the equation can be solved with the $\beta$.

Comment: I may have a solution. But first let me point out the nature of your function and ask about its context. In this and the linked question you're looking for a global minimum, in a given domain, of a sum of *radial basis functions* $G(r) = \sum_{n=1}^N \beta_n f(r-r_n)$; $r_n$ are called the centers, and $\beta_n$ -- the coefficients or the weights. You're considering both compactly supported non-smooth (did it have to be?) RBF kernel (above) and globally supported smooth RBF (in the linked question). RBF is used to approximate scattered data. What dictates $r_n$ grid?Are $z_n$ known at centers?

Comment: @rych Thanks for clarifying. The RBF kernel didn't have to be non-smooth, or compactly supported, as long as it goes to zero for r->inf. The kernel comes from an experiment where a dozen or so discrete measurements are taken. The kernel is then interpolated linearly from the data. The experiment is such that at a certain radius, the value goes to zero, so it's more accurate for the kernel to be compactly supported, but for approximation purposes asymptotic behavior is fine.

Comment: @rych $r_n$ is just the magnitude for the $(x_{n,m},y_{n,m})$ vectors, which is given by a formula I edited into the linked question. $r_n$ is just the lazy way I arbitrarily mapped (n,m) space into a single index. I don't have an actual equation for the mapping. Yes, $z_n$ is known.

Comment: @rych Is the RBF kernel strictly used to approximate scattered data or is my use of it appropriate?

Comment: There are smooth compactly-supported RBFs, e.g. if we want $C^2$, take Wendland's $f(r)=(1-r)_+^4(4r+1)$, making the sum $G(r)$ also $C^2$. Gaussians would be even better to work with. Now, if it were indeed an interpolation problem, we would be finding the coefficients $\beta_n$ such that $G(r_n)=z_n$ at all centers. Instead, you seem to consider a sum of influences from the centers ("sources"), with some prescribed weights $\beta_n$. Correct?

Comment: @rych I might have misunderstood what you meant by, "is $z_n$ known at the centers?" I was referring to $z_n$ as $G(r_n)=z_n$, which I have initially because the $\beta_n$ start off at 1 and then are optimized numerically. As the $\beta_n$ change, so do the $z_n$, which then changes the max and min. So, yes, the $\beta_n$ are prescribed originally and then we search for the min and max, then adjust the $\beta_n$ to reduce the difference between the min and max. Are you suggesting that we fix each $z_n$ and optimize all $\beta_n$ to reach that distribution?

Comment: @player100 I spoke too soon about the minimum being at the average. I tested it on a larger variety of points today and it didn't hold up. Interestingly, it still yields a decent approximation for my application.