# Minimizing a Gaussian Mixture

Tags: calculus, optimization, numerical-methods, maxima-minima, numerical-optimization

I'm trying to find the local minima, if they exist, of,

$$G(r) = \sum_{n=1}^N \beta_n e^{{-(r-r_n)}^2}$$

Such that $r$, $r_n$, and $\beta_n \in \Bbb R^+$ are positive scalars.

**Edit:**

The $r_n$ are actually a condensed form of $r_{n,m}$, which are given by a triangulation pattern in $\Bbb R^2$

$$x_{n,m} = \alpha(n+\frac{|n|}{n}\frac{1+(-1)^{m+1}}{4})$$
$$y_{n,m} = \alpha m\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$r_{n,m} = \sqrt{x_{n,m}^2+y_{n,m}^2}=\alpha\sqrt{n^2+0.75m^2+(0.125+0.5|n|(1+(-1)^{m+1}))}$$

Where $\alpha\in\Bbb R^+$ is the length of the triangle, and $n,m\in\Bbb Z$ are the indices of the grid. When calculated this way, the sum becomes,

$$G_R(r)=\sum_{n,m\in\Bbb Z}^{n^2+m^2\leq R^2}\beta_{n,m}e^{-(r-r_{n,m})^2}$$

The $\beta_{n,m}$ are equal for radii of equal magnitude, i.e.,

$$\beta_{n,m} = \beta_{i,j} \text{ if } r_{n,m} = r_{i,j}$$

So that the $\beta$ are optimized by ring.

Comment: $G(r)$ looks like Gaussian mixture distribution

Comment: @K_inverse Thanks! That's exactly what it is. Do you know of a solution off hand?

Comment: $r_{min}=\pm\infty$ because $G(\pm\infty)=0$.

Comment: @JJacquelin While that is true, it is not the solution we're looking for. We're looking for relative minima within the $r_n$.

Comment: @YuriyS Thanks. I forgot how fastidious some mathematicians can be. Common sense would make your suggestion redundant, but compilers don't run on common sense.

Comment: How did you find that last expression? I'm pretty sure it's not correct... I mean, you are solving a very nonlinear equation. This could only work for some special set of $r_n$. Do the parameters $r_n$, $\beta_n$ have some special form or connection by chance?

Comment: @YuriyS The last expression, for $r_{min}$, works if $\beta_n=1$ for all n. I found it by pseudo-induction, i.e., I saw that for N=2 there is a relative minimum halfway between the two $r_n$, which is the average. Then I calculated it for N=3 and various values of $r_n$. Then I checked it graphically for N=61, and other large values, using a program I've been building. The $\beta_n$ are just linear factors that are optimized in order to minimize the distance between the relative maximum and minimum of the sum. $r_n$ actually do have a form. I'll edit the question to show it.

Comment: @YuriyS I edited the question to show $r_n$, but I'm not sure how illuminating it will be. It has a somewhat complicated form. The $\beta_n$ actually do have some structure, in that they are equivalent for $n, n'$ if $r_n = r_{n'}$.

Comment: @YuriS You were right about that solution being incorrect. I didn't test it on a diverse enough set of points. Any suggestions for the original expression?

Comment: @YuriyS Surprisingly, the average actually does yield a minimum within my application. I think it's because the some of the $r_n$ are multiples of each other by an integer of $\alpha$. When the $r_n$ are evenly spaced, the average will be one of the $r_n$. For example, for 1,2,3, the average would be 2 and thus give a max. I think the way that the exponentials overlap in my application wind up making the overlap higher than the top of an exponential and therefore making the top of the exponential a min.

Comment: @YuriyS Check out my other question, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2966659/how-to-find-minimum-of-function-with-many-local-minima?noredirect=1#comment6155804_2966659, for more details about the actual application.